# Testing electrolytic capacitors from washing machine

Tags: capacitor

I've removed and tested a 560uF 500V capacitor and my UNI-T 210E says it's 500 mF? Now I may be a newbie but I know m is bigger than micro!

So is this capacitor faulty and this reading is an artefact of the way the meter tries to measure capacitance?
Am I doing something wrong or will this meter simply not measure this sort of capacitor accurately? I don't have any new capacitors to test the meter on maybe that's the next step?

Comment: What does this mean: *UNI-T 210E* ?

Comment: Most likely they simply did not include a µ symbol only for the cap tester. I also doubt the instrument can measure caps larger than 1000µF. Look into the manual.

Comment: The manual is not very good but there is a micro symbol. Just realised in the light of day it's 0.535 mF any way,DOH !

Comment: @SimonParker Sounds like you can answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @Kartman's comment about an ESR tester is valid; capacitance is only one characteristic of capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

According to [datasheet](https://www.uni-trend.com/html/product/General_Meters/digitalclampmeters/UT210_Series/UT210E.html) the measurement capacity goes up to:

Capacitance (F) 20mF    ±(4%+5)

So, 560uF is within the specification. Since the display count is 2000, it is unlikely that this is a form of error indication.

Comment: an ESR meter gives a more conclusive test of the health of an electrolytic. An electrolytic capacitor can be as dry as a desert but yet still measure correctly in terms of capacitance.

Comment: @Kartman, indeed. Not to mention that the 2 pages user manual doesn't help much...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for some reason it didn't register with my brain that it's display 0.525  mF which I guess is ok for 560 uF 20% tolerance on these . All the capacitors look fine anyway hmm ....